# How exclusively scrape content of <ol> in dependency to preceding <b>?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to attract the journal information on the website https://www.fed.cuhk.edu.hk/cri/faculty/prof-bai-barry/.

However, when I tried to use the below method, it attracts all the information like *Selected Research* and *Development Projects* with `ol` layer, which I don't want to get.

```
for ol in soup.select(".ar-faculty-section-content ol li"):
```

It will return all `ol` things in the class name `".ar-faculty-section-content"`.

What I expected to get is to get only `ol` content under `<b> Refereed Journal articles </b>`  tag. How can I deal with that?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `css selectors` in example to find the element by its text and use `adjacent sibling combinator` to pick the `ol` with its `li`:

```
for e in soup.select('b:-soup-contains("Refereed Journal articles") + ol li'):
    print(e.text)
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.fed.cuhk.edu.hk/cri/faculty/prof-bai-barry/', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

for e in soup.select('b:-soup-contains("Refereed Journal articles") + ol li'):
    print(e.text)
```

###### Output

```
Wang,  J., & Bai, B., (2022). Whose goal emphases play a more important role in  ESL/EFL learners’ motivation, self-regulated learning and achievement?:  Teachers’ or parents’. Research Papers in  Education, 1-22. doi:10.1080/02671522.2022.2030395. 
Guo, W. J., Lau, K. L., Wei, J., & Bai, B.  (2021). Academic subject and gender differences in high school students’  self-regulated learning of language and mathematics. Current Psychology, 1-16. doi: 10.1007/s12144-021-02120-9. 
Guo, W. J., Bai, B, & Song, H. (2021). Influences of process-based  instruction on students’ use of self-regulated learning strategies in EFL  writing. System, 1-11. doi: 10.1016/j.system.2021.102578. 
...
```

---

### EDIT

Just in fact that not all [sites](https://www.fed.cuhk.edu.hk/cri/faculty/prof-leung-kit-ying-suzannie/) have a `<b>` with text `Refereed Journal articles` above approach ends in an empty list.

If the goal is to get all publications instead, you could select the `<h5>` with text `Selected Publications` and `general sibling combinator` in combination with `nth-of-type()`:

```
for e in soup.select('h5:-soup-contains("Selected Publications") ~ ol:nth-of-type(1) li'):
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: Great !!!!!!! I am just worried about this problem after testing with other professor profile. I have to also attract conference paper if profile provided.At last, really thank you for your help. Let me finish this assignment and I can go sleep Zzzzzzzzzzzzz